# Facebook not picking up on og:image when sharing post

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I made a post on WordPress, then shared it on a Facebook page. In the past, the shared image would be the large "post" image. But now, for some reason, it's using the thumbnail. [Running the url through fb's debugger shows that Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.animationmagazine.net%2Ffeatures%2Fpixar-to-debut-short-sanjays-super-team-at-annecy%2F) recognizes both `og:image`s, but that neither of them are being used in the share preview. Once posted, it uses the thumbnail.

I checked the meta content in the page head just to double check and sure enough, it looks fine:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="##">
```

What's causing this? It's recognized, but not used. What?

Comment: The image doesn't exist. Gives a 404.

Comment: @Tobi where do you see the 404? If you check the og:image property, it clearly shows both images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I currently facing the same issue, after contacting facebook, it turns out there is an issue in Open Graph in facebook that affects some users.

The Bug has been reported and assigned as "high priority" in Facebook support center - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/978421888869140/

Comment: Thank you! So...turns out that, until this bug is fixed, Open Graph will pull the correct image only if you *manually* type the url in on the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

You need at least images of 1200x630 pixels size to be able to get a large preview image.

Furthermore, you should put the larger image first IMHO.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/optimizing#cachingimages
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#images

Comment: Image size isn't the issue right now. I just uploaded an image that was like 1209x700 and still got the same result.